# Is my IP in my database, if so find timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, ip

OK, so I want to know this:

Is my IP in my database? If yes, find the timestamp of entry.

So far I have this:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$myip = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM votes WHERE ip = '$ip'");

If(mysql_num_rows($myip) > 0){
//find timestamp and name it as a variable e.g $ipTime
```

Thats as far as I've got, and for the life of me, I'm a little stuck, anyone help me?

Comment: [I wish my IP address could contain an apostrophe](http://xkcd.com/327/). Maybe sometime in the future?

Comment: [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) But for new code, please use [PDO](http://www.php.net/PDO) and its prepared statements

Comment: Read up on the basic usage of MYSQL.

Comment: made me chuckle. Describes my everyday understanding of MySQL. @Wrikken thanks for the link.

Comment: do you have a timestamp field in your DB table? Perhaps you could show us the structure of your DB table so we can see enough info to help you?

Comment: i do have a time stamp which is automatically updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, it should get the timestamp and convert it to a human readable format, you may also want to look up the PHP `date()` function to adjust the `$date_format` to your liking which can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Fetch IP

$query = mysql_query("SELECT `timestamp` FROM `votes` WHERE (`ip` = '$ip')") or die(mysql_error()); // Queries IP

$amount = mysql_num_rows($query); // Amount of times listed (rows)

if ($amount > 0) { // If exists

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    $timestamp = $row['timestamp'];

    $date_format = 'm F \a\t g:ia';
    $date = date("$date_format", $timestamp); // Converts timestamp

    echo("Your IP Address (".$ip.") is already listed at ".$date."");

} else {

    echo("Your IP Address is not currently listed");

}
```

Comment: thanks! Very in depth. I know alot about the date function in PHP but never really thought of this approach towards a timestamp.